# react-navigation How to set tabBar margin corresponding to Animated Value

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation `Tab Navigation`. I have a header above my tab navigation and it can collapse and expand corresponding to the `scrollView`.

This is my problem: When I scroll all the way up, the header will collapse and thats what I want but the tabBar will stay static(Please see the photo). Is there a way I could set the `tabBar margin` corresponding to the scrollview? So that there is no `marginTop` when the header is collapsed.

[image]

```
const Header_Maximum_Height = 40;
const Header_Minimum_Height = 0;

export default class App extends Component {

  render(){
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, marginTop:30}}>
        <AppContainer/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends Component{
      constructor()
    {
         super();
         this.AnimatedHeaderValue = new Animated.Value(0);
     }
render() {

const AnimateHeaderBackgroundColor = this.AnimatedHeaderValue.interpolate(
   {
    inputRange: [ 0, ( Header_Maximum_Height - Header_Minimum_Height )  ],
    outputRange: [ '#009688', '#00BCD4' ],
    extrapolate: 'clamp'
   });

const AnimateHeaderHeight = this.AnimatedHeaderValue.interpolate(
      {
       inputRange: [ 0, ( Header_Maximum_Height - Header_Minimum_Height ) ],
       outputRange: [ Header_Maximum_Height, Header_Minimum_Height ],
       extrapolate: 'clamp'
                  });
          return (
                  <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>

                  <Animated.View style={{height:AnimateHeaderHeight,width:'100%', backgroundColor:'gray'}}>
                    <Text style={{color:'white'}}> Collapsible Expandable Header </Text>
                  </Animated.View>

                    <Animated.ScrollView
                                      scrollEventThrottle = { 16 }
                                      onScroll = { Animated.event(
                                        [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.AnimatedHeaderValue }}}]
                                  )}>

                        <ImageBackground
                        style={{width:375, height:400}}
                        source={require('./assets/pizza.jpg')}>
                        </ImageBackground>

                 </Animated.ScrollView>
                 </SafeAreaView>
                          );
                        }
                      }
    const tabBarHeight = 100

    const AppTabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({

      Home:{
      screen:HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
          header: null,
          tabBarVisible:true,
          activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
        }
      }, {
        tabBarOptions: {
         showLabel: true,
          style: {
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(22, 22, 22, 0)',
              position: 'absolute',
              Top:  Dimensions.get('window').height-tabBarHeight,
              left:0,
              right:0,
//I initially set the margin to 45 but as I scroll up How can I set the marginTop to 0 when I reach the top screen.
              marginTop:45
          },
          labelStyle:{
            fontSize:15,
            color:"white"
          }
        }
       }
      )
```

I also tried `marginTop` to `this.AnimatedHeaderValue` but doesn't seem to work. Any advise or comments would be really helpful.

Comment: Can you provide a working example of your code which demonstrates the issue? It would be much easier to debug. Based on the information you provided I can only make speculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `listener` on the [Animated.event](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated#event) that would allow you to get the value of your `y`:

```
<Animated.ScrollView
  scrollEventThrottle={16}
  onScroll={Animated.event(
    [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.AnimatedHeaderValue }}}],
    {
      useNativeDriver: true,
      listener: event => {
        const offsetY = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y
        this.onScrollChange(offsetY)
      }
    },
  )}
>
  <ImageBackground
    style={{ width: 375, height: 400 }}
    source={require('./assets/pizza.jpg')}
  />
</Animated.ScrollView>
```

Here, you just need to define the `onScrollChange` in your component. Because your `marginTop` is in your top-level `<App />`, it will be a little tricky to change, so you could potentially use Redux or a [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to update and use this value.

You could also put the margin at the same level and use a state, but that would force you to do the same for every page depending on your architecture.

---

Because you need to change on runtime the `tabBarOptions`, you're going to need to create and provide a custom `tabBarComponent` to your navigator:

```
const AppTabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
        tabBarVisible: true,
        activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    tabBarComponent: CustomTabBar
  },
)
```

This component will extend the default component used by react-navigation, and hook into a state.

```
import React from 'react'
import { MaterialTopTabBar } from 'react-navigation'

export default ({ hasMargin, ...props }) => (
  <MaterialTopTabBar
    {...props}
    showLabel
    labelStyle={{
      fontSize: 15,
      color: 'white',
    }}
    style={{
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(22, 22, 22, 0)',
      position: 'absolute',
      top: Dimensions.get('window').height-tabBarHeight,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      marginTop: hashMargin ? 45 : 0,
    }}
  />
)
```

The problem here is that you won't have the variable `hasMargin`. You will need to either choose to either `connect` your component [using Redux](https://redux.js.org) or [use a React context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Both require some understanding and configuration, so you might need to read up a bit on them. Once it's done, define `onScrollChange` to change your context or dispatch a redux action.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I think should work! But i don't understand the `onScrollChange` part. Are you saying I should create a handler `onScrollChange` ? if so what should be inside it?

Comment: It should be a function in your component with the `ScrollView` receiving the offset as a parameter. Inside this function you will need to check if the offset is 0, and modify a variable which would be used to tell if your top level View should have a margin or not.

Comment: I wish I could fully understand you. I am really new to animation. If possible, could you please provide the full code?

Comment: This is not really about animation and more about state management, which is a bit out of scope of your question. I'm going to detail a bit more but it's likely documenting yourself on state will be beneficial to you and your understanding of React

Comment: thank you very much for the detail i will go through the documentation! Still one question, what is `{...props}` for?

Comment: Let's say the `props` object is `{ a: 1, b: 2 }`, it will give each of the props of the object to the component, it's called object spreading